# NodeJs Express Session ID persists on Local Machine but resets on cloud server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, digital-ocean, amazon-ec2

I have a web application that uses nodejs with express-session.  When I run my app locally (127.0.0.1) the session id is the same for every request I make.  However, when I run my app on Amazon's EC2 server, the session ID changes for each request, making it impossible for my login system to work.

I know that a new session ID is being created on the EC2 server because I put a console.log statement that prints out req.session.id within my authentication route.  I also look in my sessions collection through mongodb and see a new session document with a different session id being created for each request.

My client is making requests directly to the "Elastic IP" address of my EC2 instance.  I'm not sure what Elastic IP is but it seems to behave like a public IP address.

I'm going to try to post all the relevant code now.

server.js

```
var fs                  = require('fs'),
    express             = require('express'),
    app                 = express(),
    https               = require('https').createServer({
                              key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
                              cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
                          }, app),
    bodyParser          = require('body-parser'),
    logger              = require('morgan'),
    cookieParser        = require('cookie-parser'),
    methodOverride      = require('method-override'),
    session             = require('express-session'),
    passport            = require('passport'),
    config              = require('./config.js'),
    MongoStore          = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    sessionStore        = new MongoStore({ url:     'mongodb://127.0.0.1/Jibber' }),    
    passportSocketIo    = require("passport.socketio"),
    sessionSecret       = config.sessionSecret,
    sessionKey          = config.sessionKey,

app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(logger('combined'));
app.use(cookieParser(sessionSecret));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'false'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(session({
    secret: sessionSecret,
    key: sessionKey,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 60000 * 60
    }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Session-persisted message middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var err = req.session.error,
        msg = req.session.notice,
        success = req.session.success;

    delete req.session.error;
    delete req.session.success;
    delete req.session.notice;

    if (err) res.locals.error = err;
    if (msg) res.locals.notice = msg;
    if (success) res.locals.success = success;

    next();
});

app.get('/loggedin', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.id);
    res.json(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : false);
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    console.log("LOGGIN OUT " + req.user.username)
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy();
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/logout-success.html');
});

https.listen(config.port, config.serverUrl, function() {
    console.log("App listening on port " + config.port);
});
```

This is my first time using Amazon's EC2 server so I feel this problem is caused by the server and not by the code.  I'm going to try running my code on another server and see if it produces the same problem.  I'll keep you guys posted on this.

I also just wanted to mention that a lot of the code I took out was passport authentication code using google, facebook, and twitter. I don't really think it's the problem though as it seems it's more of a non-persisting session problem rather than an authentication problem.  But I can post the code if need be.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE: I created a new cloud server through DigitalOcean and the problem occurs on there as well!  It must be a cloud server thing...I emailed support with DigitalOcean.  Hopefully they have an answer!

Comment: Can you check if a cookie is set?

Comment: @Roland Starke  Yes, a cookie is set.  One interesting thing to note though is that the content (though encrypted) never changes with each request.

Comment: Mh always different session id but same cookie? strange. Some other hint: move `express.static` above your cookie parser. So if a static file is requested you respont fast. If there is no need for parsing the body ,cookies or starting a session for static files. You will save some CPU

Comment: Thanks for that tip :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok I figured it out.  I had to add {Access-Controll-Allow-Credentials, true} and also had to set my Access Control Allow Origin to my chrome extension url.